# How to 'get' data from a JSON file to another composable function?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let me simplify:

MyScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    context: Context,
) {
    var quotes by remember { mutableStateOf<List<Quotes>>(emptyList())}

    LaunchedEffect(context) {
        quotes = readJsonFromAssets(context, "quotes.json")
    }

}

suspend fun readJsonFromAssets(context: Context, fileName: String): List<Quotes> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val jsonString = context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        val gson = Gson()
        gson.fromJson(jsonString, Array<Quotes>::class.java).toList()
    }
}
```

In the above code, i'm reading the JSON file and storing the data in the 'quotes' variable.

Now I want to access this data in another composable or even main activity. How do i do this?

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting

Comment: Read json data in parent activity, and pass it to which composeable you need, but it is better to use a viewModel to access and manage app data

Comment: @ucMedia I tried using the viewModel approach twice. But my app keeps crashing. So i thought maybe using viewModel is the problem. But i'll look into this approach since you said it. thanks.